# Let $f : R\rightarrow(0, 1)$ be a continuous function. Then, which of the following function(s) has(have) the value zero in the interval $(0, 1)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $f : R\rightarrow(0, 1)$ be a continuous function. Then, which of the following function(s) has(have) the value zero at some point in the interval $(0, 1)$

A) $e^x-\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\sin(t)dt$

B) $f(x)+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(t)\sin(t)dt$

C) $x-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}f(t)\cos(t)dt$

D) $x^9-f(x)$

My attempt is as follows:-

**Let's first look at $B$ option**

$f(x)$ is a positive function i.e $f(x)>0$ $\forall$ x , $f(t)\sin(t)$ will also be positive function as $\sin$ is positive in $\left(0,1\right)$

So the net area of $f(t)\sin(t)$ from $0$ to $x$ will also be positive as the graph of $f(t)\sin(t)$ is always above $X$ axis.

So $f(x)+\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\sin(t)dt$ cannot ever be zero in interval $(0,1)$

**Let's take a look at $D$ option**

$x^9$ is a positive function for $x\in(0,1)$, $f(x)$ is also a positive function.

So suppose if at $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$, $f\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^9$, then $x^9-f(x)$ will get $0$

So $x^9-f(x)$ can get zero depending on the values of $f(x)$

**Let's look at $A$ option**

For $x\in(0,1)$, $e^x\in(1,e)$

But maximum value of $f(t)\sin(t)$ will always be less than $1$ as both $f(t)<1$ and $\sin(t)<1$ for $x\in(0,1)$

So $f(t)\sin t<1$

$$\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\sin tdt<\int_{0}^{x}1dt$$

$$\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\sin tdt<x$$

As $x\in(0,1)$. So, $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\sin(t)<1$

Hence $e^x-\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\sin(t)dt \ne 0$ because $e^x\ge1$ for $x\ge0$

**Let's look at $C$ option**

$$0<f(t)\cos(t)<1$$
$$0<\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}f(t)\cos(t)dt<\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}1dt$$
$$0<\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}f(t)\cos(t)dt<\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x$$

For $x\in(0,1)$, $\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x\in\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-1,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$

Approximately, $\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x\in\left(\dfrac{8}{14},\dfrac{22}{14}\right)$ approximating $\pi$ as $\dfrac{22}{7}$

$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}f(t)\cos(t)dt$ can be less than $1$ for some $x\in(0,1)$. So may be for some $x$ it can be equal to $x$ but we can't predict such $x$ as we don't know $f(x)$

But actual answer is only $D$. What am I missing here. According to my analysis it should be option $C$ and $D$

Answer (score 4):

The given answer is wrong. For C) let $g(x)=x-\int_0^{\pi/2 -x} f(t)\cos tdt$. Then $g$ is continuous,  $g(0) <0$ and $g(1)=1-\int_0^{\pi/2 -1} f(t)\cos tdt> 1-\int_0^{\pi/2 -1} \cos tdt=1-\sin (\pi/2-1) >0.$  Hence there exists $x \in (0,1)$ such that $g(x)=0$. So the correct options are C) and D).